# Get generic Collection based on return type / callers perferences

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm trying to return a Collection Implementation based on the callers need.

```
private <T, C extends Collection<T>> C getCollection() {
   ...  
}
```

For instance I want to call the method like so:

```
Set<String> set = getCollection();
```

which returns an empty Set applicable for Strings.

Anyone an idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: That’s impossible. `getCollection()` doesn’t know what the caller wants. There’s no benefit in writing `Set<String> set = getCollection();` instead of `Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();` anyway.

Comment: You would have to be able to create instances of generic types for that, which is not possible.